# SQL - Calculate relative amounts within a year from date segments

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am currently coding an existing Payroll system and I have the below problem. I need to count the Vacation days taken of one employee in one year in order to transfer them to the next. The days can be either complete, or hours in a day (e.g. 6 hour vacation from default 8 hour working day)

However the existing functionality only stores the aforementioned data in a table with columns like this.

```
EmployeeID  | StartDate   | EndDate     | Hours

1             01-02-2018    04-02-2018       24
1             08-03-2018    08-03-2018        4
2             30-12-2017    04-01-2018       48
3             30-12-2018    04-01-2019       48
```

Now the issue is that I want to limit the dates to the previous year only. So since we have 2019, I need vacations only from 2018. Meaning records with different Start and End Year, need special handling

The result table should look like this

```
EmployeeID   |   HoursPreviousYear

1                               28
2                               32
3                               16
```

I am already aware of some helpful SQL functions such as DATEDIFF() or YEAR(), but since each record is different, I would probably need to use a cursor and iterate the table. Then to pass the results to a different table, I would have create in the query and return it.

To be honest I am baffled...

I never had to use cursors before and as far as I can see, I am not sure even if I can return a table as a result (which I also need to use in a join later on). I am not sure if it is worth to continue struggling with it, but it seems that there should be an easier way.

My other option was to change the behavior of the Save button, to save 2 different records, with no overlapping years, but I cannot since we are having legacy data...

Comment: What logic did you use to get 16 hours for employee 3.. nvm you assume 8 hours

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously some edge cases where this isn't thorough enough, but it should get you started.

This assumes 8 hours taken per day off, totally fails to account for date ranges that span a weekend or holiday, and wouldn't account for someone taking, say three full days off followed by a half day.

```
DECLARE @Year int = 2018;

SELECT
  EmployeeID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN StartDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,1,1) 
            THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year-1,12,31),EndDate)*8
           WHEN EndDate > DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,12,31) 
            THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year+1,1,1))*8
           ELSE [Hours] 
      END) AS HoursPreviousYear
FROM
  @table
GROUP BY
  EmployeeID;

+------------+-------------------+
| EmployeeID | HoursPreviousYear |
+------------+-------------------+
|          1 |                28 |
|          2 |                32 |
|          3 |                16 |
+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: It never occured to me to actually count the weekends and such. It seems to me the general solution provided is just wrong and needs further analysis. Say though, is it possible to reach to the same result using cursor???

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIFF to calculate additional days for start and end date to deduct extra hours from total hours as shown in the following query-

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
SUM(Hours) - (SUM(StDiff)+SUM(EndDiff))*8 HoursPreviousYear
FROM
(
    SELECT EmployeeID,
    CONVERT(DATE, StartDate , 103) StartDate,
    CONVERT(DATE, EndDate , 103) EndDate,
    Hours,
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, StartDate , 103)) = 2018 THEN 0 
        ELSE DATEDIFF(DD,CONVERT(DATE, StartDate , 103),CONVERT(DATE, '01-01-2018' , 103)) 
    END StDiff,
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, EndDate , 103)) = 2018 THEN 0 
        ELSE DATEDIFF(DD,CONVERT(DATE, '31-12-2018' , 103),CONVERT(DATE, EndDate , 103)) 
    END EndDiff
    FROM your_table
    WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, StartDate , 103)) <= 2018
    AND YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, EndDate , 103)) >= 2018
)A
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```